# Finding sphere of influence in multibody system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, solar-system, celestial-mechanics

I would like to draw a boundary illustrating the [sphere of influence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_of_influence_%28astrodynamics%29) of each body in a 3 body system. What is the best way to find such a boundary?

My understanding is at the edge an SoI is the minimum of the sum of gravitational forces. My current method is, for each body, project a line from the body to some fixed point well beyond the size of the system, and find the minimum net gravitational force by binary intersection. Is there a faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your definition of sphere of influence is incorrect. You could also be confusing the sphere of influence with the Hill sphere.

The [sphere of influence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_of_influence_%28astrodynamics%29) has mainly an application in the patched conic approximation, and the word sphere is even another approximation. A [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81991/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-gravitational-sphere-of-influence-soi/) asks about the derivation of the radius of this sphere. The core of the [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81991/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-gravitational-sphere-of-influence-soi/91079#91079) I gave is that the actual surface of the sphere of influence is defined by the ratio of primary and the perturbing gravity source. The perturbing gravity is not the same as its total gravity, since the primary source is also attracted to it. I am not certain if this method can be altered to be applied to three bodies, who exert a gravitational forces. You might be able to derive it for certain situations, such as for [Trojan asteroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Trojan) and just include the extra perturbation of Jupiter to the perturbation of the sun. However it will be harder for systems of more equal masses, such that there might be points in space where instead two, three spheres, or rather areas, of influences meet.

The [Hill sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere) is an approximated limit of the distance at which a satellite can still orbit a celestial body in a stable manner. And as David Hammen and the Wikipedia article stated, stable prograde orbits are limited to about 1/3 to 1/2 the Hill radius, while retrograde orbits are stable at larger distances.

Comment: I don't know why this question was recently modified by "Community", but it was. I'm not going to downvote this answer, but it is not correct. The Hill sphere is not what you say it is. It's an approximation regarding stability. Objects in a prograde orbit will easily escape if they orbit at more than about 1/3 the Hill sphere radius. Objects in a retrograde orbit remain stable for a **long** time even if they orbit at a bit more than the Hill sphere radius.

Comment: @DavidHammen I will edit my answer, at the moment of writing my answer I mainly focused on the sphere of influence and not so much on the properties of the Hill sphere.

Answer (score 0):

find the center of mass of three bodies $M_3$, and three pairwise centers of masses. send the rays from $M_3$ to $M_{21},M_{13},M_{23}$, they'll divide the space to triangles of influence

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks! But what about the areas outside the triangle?

Comment: ok, I might not describe it clearly. $M_3$ is the center from which three rays will go to infinity, dividing the space into three areas (not triangles). if three masses were equal, then it would be three rays with 120 degrees between them.

Comment: @Aksakal is what you are describing something analog to a weighted Voronoi diagram?